# Text property on SelectListItem is unexpectedly truncated

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and I'm trying to display the text from one of the items, however, only the first word in the relevant field is displaying: the output reads "4th" instead of "4th grade."

This is how I am populating the `ViewBag`:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGradeLevelItems(int selectedGradeLevelId = 0)
{
    var allGradeLevels = _courseRepository.GetAllGradeLevels();
    var gradeLevelItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

    if (selectedGradeLevelId == 0) //if 0, we're creating a new course. Let's add a default option to the list
    {
        gradeLevelItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "--Choose--", Selected = true });
    }
    else if (allGradeLevels != null && allGradeLevels.All(gl => gl.GradeLevelId != selectedGradeLevelId)) //if the selected grade level is not in the table
    {
        selectedGradeLevelId = allGradeLevels?.Min(gl => gl.GradeLevelId) ?? 0;
    }

    allGradeLevels?.ForEach(gl => gradeLevelItems.Add(new SelectListItem(){
        Text = gl.GradeLevelName,
        Value = gl.GradeLevelId.ToString(),
        Selected = (gl.GradeLevelId == selectedGradeLevelId)
    }));

    return gradeLevelItems;
}
```

Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GradeLevelId, new {@class = "row control-label details-label"})
    <div class="row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled value=@ViewBag.GradeList[(int)(@Model.GradeLevelId ?? 0)].Text />    
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please post more code, what is the model m class structure? The value is getting set as logic on a ViewBag property, where is the Viewbag being set? Can you move said logic to the controller?

Comment: Thanks. [This link](https://gist.github.com/jekrch/54ae9b92ead78cb455dd) should include all of the relevant code, but let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please verify what values are stored in your grade levels database table (I presume that's where they come from)

Comment: Try quotes around the attribute - `value = "@ViewBag...."`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, using the quotes around the attribute worked! Thanks for reply! If you add this as a solution, I'll be happy to mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes around the attribute value

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" disabled value="@ViewBag.GradeList[(int)(@Model.GradeLevelId ?? 0)].Text" />
```